# How Do I Bring in Google-sheets If Sidebar Menu Item is Selected

Tags: r, user-interface, google-sheets, shiny, shinydashboard

So I have a single Shiny application that I am building out. My goal is to try to bring in Google Sheets that have Connected to our Salesforce Database. I have abstracted it to Google Sheets and have created charts and data tables that refresh dynamically through our company's salesforce to google suite integration. This allows me to bring in the data and visualize it more freely without having to really build out the dashboards in Salesforce because Salesforce is so expensive. So currently I have been building out the shiny code with R studio. I have gotten a pretty nice layout.

1. I am trying to bring in google charts that are embedded within a webpage using the google charts library
2. I am trying to interactively get data tables to generate with box plots showing the google charts below the data tables within the UI.

I have already tried to set it inside the sidebar menu output as a data frame. However, I have not been successful.

```
#
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application. You can
# run the application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
# 
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

## app.R ##
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(rsconnect)
library(googlesheets)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(mosaic)
library(DT)
library(googleCharts)
library(fontawesome)


# Google Sheets for Synced Keys with Data Master
gs_auth(new_user = FALSE)
handover <- gs_key("1Wu8gJyzw6o7BS4GoR7pM_NofHyXvOzDMK3O-VVHcB8c")
#cr_mw_data <- gs_key("Insert_Key")
sev3_sev4_data <- 
gs_key("1ga7s1vgMhYRNvr2WL6vjv_VRYtP5nI0aMoweLAjB6v4")
#all_alerts_data <- gs_key("Insert_Key")
#case_wo_key_5 <- gs_key("Insert_Key")
#sc_sev_1_cases <- gs_key("Insert_Key")
#subscriptios <- gs_key("Insert_Key")
bimonthly_ttr <- gs_key("1TiQeStsuwATHWxExV_Pdb2rSuOlOPB3KcYbPKFOj8VQ")


for_gs_sheet <- gs_read(handover)
str(for_gs_sheet)

for_gs_sheet <- gs_read(sev3_sev4_data)
str(for_gs_sheet)

for_gs_sheet <- gs_read(bimonthly_ttr)
str(for_gs_sheet)

## Identifies the Google Sheet in Question
## handover_sheet = gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wu8gJyzw6o7BS4GoR7pM_NofHyXvOzDMK3O-VVHcB8c/edit#gid=0")
## bimonthly_ttr = gs_url("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TiQeStsuwATHWxExV_Pdb2rSuOlOPB3KcYbPKFOj8VQ/edit#gid=0")
#shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(height = 1080))

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                dashboardHeader(title = "Miradashboard",
                                # This drop-down menu offers user and system administration within the application
                                dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                                             messageItem(
                                               from = "Sales Dept",
                                               message = "Sales are steady this month."
                                             ),
                                             messageItem(
                                               from = "New User",
                                               message = "How do I register?",
                                               icon = icon("question"),
                                               time = "13:45"
                                             ),
                                             messageItem(
                                               from = "Support",
                                               message = "The new server is ready.",
                                               icon = icon("life-ring"),
                                               time = "2014-12-01"
                                             )
                                ),
                                # This is a drop-down menu for checking notifications.
                                # This should alert users of alerts that have not been merged to a case in the last 15 days.
                                dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                                             notificationItem(
                                               text = "5 new users today",
                                               icon("users")
                                             ),
                                             notificationItem(
                                               text = "12 items delivered",
                                               icon("truck"),
                                               status = "success"
                                             ),
                                             notificationItem(
                                               text = "Server load at 86%",
                                               icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                               status = "warning"
                                             )
                                ),
                                # This is a drop-down menu for checking tasks.
                                # This drop-down menu will eventually offer suggestions based off of ML Algorithms.
                                dropdownMenu(type = "tasks", badgeStatus = "success",
                                             taskItem(value = 90, color = "green",
                                                      "Documentation"
                                             ),
                                             taskItem(value = 17, color = "aqua",
                                                      "Project X"
                                             ),
                                             taskItem(value = 75, color = "yellow",
                                                      "Server deployment"
                                             ),
                                             taskItem(value = 80, color = "red",
                                                      "Overall project"
                                             )
                                )
                ),

                dashboardSidebar(
                  ## Sidebar content
                  dashboardSidebar(
                    sidebarMenu(
                      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                      menuItem("Data", icon = icon("th"), href = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ga7s1vgMhYRNvr2WL6vjv_VRYtP5nI0aMoweLAjB6v4/edit#gid=1342420852"),
                      menuItem("Widgets", icon = icon("th"), href = "https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/", newtab = FALSE),
                      menuItem("Mirantis Directory", icon = icon("sitemap") ,href = "https://directory.mirantis.com/#/resources/staffing"),
                      menuItem("Reports", tabName = "reports", icon = icon("chart-line"), startExpanded = FALSE,
                               menuSubItem("All Alerts", tabName = "All Alerts", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("All CR & MW", tabName = "All CR & MW", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("Sev3 & Sev4 Data", tabName = "Sev3 & Sev4 Data", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("SC Sev1 Cases", tabName = "SC Sev1 Cases", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("Cases with Key 5 Updates", tabName = "Cases with Key 5 Updates", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("Cases without Key 5 Updates", tabName = "Cases without Key 5 Updates", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("Auto Refresh Execution Log", tabName = "Auto Refresh Execution Log", icon = icon("dna")),
                               menuSubItem("L1 Oncall", tabName = "L1 Oncall", icon = icon("calendar-alt")),
                               menuSubItem("TET Oncall", tabName = "TET Oncall", icon = icon("calendar-alt")),
                               menuSubItem("SME Oncall", tabName = "SME Oncall", icon = icon("calendar-alt")),
                               menuSubItem("AT&T Oncall", tabName = "AT&T Oncall", icon = icon("calendar-alt"))
                               ),
                      menuItem("OpsCare Clients", tabName = "OpsCare Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), startExpanded = FALSE,
                               menuSubItem("All Cases", tabName = "All Cases", icon = icon("bezier-curve")),
                               menuSubItem("All Alerts", tabName = "All Alerts", icon = icon("bezier-curve")),
                               menuSubItem("TTR Metrics by Customer", tabName = "TTR Metrics by Customer", icon = icon("bezier-curve"))
                               ),
                      menuItem("Top 10 Clients", tabName = "Top 10 Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o"), startExpanded = FALSE,
                               menuSubItem("Adobe Systems", tabName = "Adobe Systems", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Apple Inc", tabName = "Apple Inc", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("AT&T Inc", tabName = "AT&T Inc", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Cox Communications", tabName = "Cox Communications", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Edge Gravity by Ericsson", tabName = "Edge Gravity by Ericsson", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Ericsson - Mediakind", tabName = "Ericsson - Mediakind", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Ericcson Telefonakatiebolaget LM Ericsson", tabName = "Ericcson Telefonakatiebolaget LM Ericsson", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Inspur", tabName = "Inspur", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Reliance", tabName = "Reliance", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Shanghai Xietong (Sharetome)", tabName = "Shanghai Xietong (Sharetome)", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("State Street Corporation", tabName = "State Street Corporation", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Volkswaggen", tabName = "Volkswaggen", icon = icon("address-card")),
                               menuSubItem("Other Clients", tabName = "Other Clients", icon = icon("address-card"))
                      ),
                      menuItem("ProdCare Clients", tabName = "ProdCare Clients", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
                      menuItem("Alerts", tabName = "Alerts", icon = icon("bar-chart-o")),
                      menuItem("Change Requests", tabName = "Change Requests", icon = icon("list-alt")),
                      menuItem("Maintenance Windows", tabName = "Maintenance Windows", icon = icon("list-alt")),
                      menuItem("Rundeck", icon = icon("code"), 
                               href = "https://rundeck.suplab01.snv.mirantis.net/user/login"),
                      menuItem("Salesforce", icon = icon("database"), 
                               href = "https://mirantis.my.salesforce.com/"),
                      menuItem("Handovers", icon = icon("google"), 
                               href = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wu8gJyzw6o7BS4GoR7pM_NofHyXvOzDMK3O-VVHcB8c/edit#gid=0"),
                      menuItem("Jump-Host Access", tabName = "Jump-Host Access", icon = icon("bars")),
                      menuItem("Mirantis HT Wiki", icon = icon("bars"), 
                               href = "https://mirantis.jira.com/wiki/spaces/2S/pages/1254621239/L1+-+General+Queue+Help+Desk+Team"),
                      menuItem("Slack", icon = icon("slack"), href = "https://miracloud.slack.com"),
                      menuItem("Source code", icon = icon("github"), 
                               href = "https://github.com/Richard-Barrett/Miradashboard")
                    )
                  )
                ),
                dashboardBody(
                  # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
                  fluidRow(
                    #box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                    #box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
                    #box(plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)),
                    #box(plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)),
                    h1("Handovers"),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable", width = "auto", height = "auto"),
                    #box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                    #box(gs_read(ss, ws = "handover")),
                    #box(plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)),
                    #box(plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)),

                    #Example Attachment Box 
                    #box(
                    #  title = "Attachment example",
                    #  attachmentBlock(
                    #    src = "http://kiev.carpediem.cd/data/afisha/o/2d/c7/2dc7670333.jpg",
                    #    title = "Test",
                    #    title_url = "http://google.com",
                    #    "This is the content"
                    #  )
                    #),
                    box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                    box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
                    #box(dataTableOutput("DT1", height = 250))
                    box(
                      title = "Controls",
                      sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 2, 200, 50)
                    )
                  )
                )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)


  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
df <- gs_read(handover)
  })

  # List Server Output whereby plot[1-#] is the plot box output in UI above.
  # Server Output occurs and is defined by data variables
  # histdata[seq_len(input$slider)] defines slider utilization
  # hist(data) defines histogram off of "data"
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
  })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
  })
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
  })
  output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
hist(data)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The actual results have led to the handover spreadsheet sitting as a data table on the main screen as soon as I run the application. However, I would like it if a person selected the actual sidebar menu items that it would point to and load a different data table from a different sheet.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally wrapped my brain around it.
First and foremost you need to have the googlesheets package installed and loaded on your R session.

```
library(googlesheets)
```

After which you need to have the the basics down to bring in the sheet. 
So from here specify the sheet as a data frame.

```
google_sheet_df <- gs_key("<insert_key_after_the_/d/###forkey_id>")
```

from here you have the UI, BODY, and SERVER codes for the shiny app. 
In the

```
sidebarMenu(menuItem("ITEM NAME", tabName = "NAME_TAG", icon = icon("dna"))),
dashboardBody(tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "NAME_TAG",fluidRow(
DT::dataTableOutput("mytable",width = "auto, height = "auto"))))),
server <- function(input, output) {
set.seed(122)
histdata <- rnorm(500)


## Data Table Outputs from Google Sheets
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
df <- gs_read(google_sheet_df) ##NAME OF GOOGLE SHEET DF
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The most important part is that you render the dataTableOutput in the server output and then reference the DT in the body embedded within the specified tabItem you want it to show if you click on it.